# Selecionar um selectbox a partir de um click de uma tabela

Tags: php, javascript, pdo

Olá estou tentando passar os dados de uma tabela puxada do banco para os campos a qual pertencem para atualizar na mesma pagina em que se cadastra mas consigo apenas passar os dados dos textbox a pagina é em php.

Abaixo a lógica que eu estava usando.

```
$("#selUsuario").on('click', 'tr', function () {
var idUser = $(this).find(':nth-child(1)').text();
var nomeUser = $(this).find(':nth-child(2)').text();
var areaUser = $(this).find(':nth-child(3)').text();
var emailUser = $(this).find(':nth-child(4)').text();
var emiteUser = $(this).find(':nth-child(5)').text();
var origemUser = $(this).find(':nth-child(6)').text();
var masterUser = $(this).find(':nth-child(7)').text();


$(this).siblings().removeClass("marcada");
$(this).toggleClass("marcada");


$("#txtUsuario").val(idUser);
$("#txtNome").val(nomeUser);
    $("#sbSetor").val(areaUser);    
    $("#sbEmite").val (emiteUser);
    $("#sbOrigem").val (origemUser);
$("#sbMaster").val (masterUser);
```

});

Comment: eu ja sei o que você consegue, porem nao sei o que você não consegue. o que você quer fazer na verdade?

Comment: Eu queria preencher um selectbox com a informação que eu capturo no momento em que a linha for clicada, os campos que não consigo preencher são esses com "sb" e com os textbox funcionam.